# How to change sentence with a common pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Alexa, thank you for visiting Chicago! We hope you come back soon!
Katana, thank you for visiting Dallas! We hope you come back soon!
Siri, thank you for visiting New York City! We hope you come back soon!
Bixby, thank you for visiting Seattle! We hope you come back soon!
Assuming these are values in a column on an arbitrary table, how would I write a SQL query that'll replace all of the above to "*First Name*, thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!"
Although these are only four rows, I'm working with over 500 that need to be edited.

I'm using T-SQL/SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using stuff is probably the easiest way:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @sampleData as TABLE
(
    sentence varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
('Alexa, thank you for visiting Chicago! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Katana, thank you for visiting Dallas! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Siri, thank you for visiting New York City! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Bixby, thank you for visiting Seattle! We hope you come back soon!')
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE @sampleData 
SET sentence = STUFF(sentence, 
                     charindex(',', sentence), 
                     len(sentence), 
                     ', thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!')
```

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM @sampleData 
WHERE sentence LIKE '%, thank you for visiting %! We hope you come back soon!'
```

Results:

```
sentence
Alexa, thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!
Katana, thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!
Siri, thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!
Bixby, thank you for visiting Los Angeles! We hope you come back soon!
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/CWONV79642)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what this has to do with `REPLACE()`.  I would write this as:

```
update t
    set col = 'Thank you for visiting Los Angeles!'
    where col in ('Thank you for visiting Chicago!',
                  'Thank you for visiting Dallas!',
                  'Thank you for visiting New York City!',
                  'Thank you for visiting Seattle!'
                 );
```

Comment: I apologize, I didn't provide enough information with my original question. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
update t
    set col =
        select left(col,charindex('visiting',col,1)+8) + 'Los Angelese!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #StackTest
(
    Sentence varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #StackTest
        ( Sentence )
VALUES
('Alexa, thank you for visiting Los Angeles!'),
('Katana, thank you for visiting Chicago!'),
('Siri, thank you for visiting Dallas!'),
('Bixby, thank you for visiting New York City!')

SELECT
    'First Name' + SUBSTRING(Sentence, CHARINDEX(',', Sentence, 1), LEN(Sentence) - CHARINDEX(',', Sentence, 1))
FROM
    #StackTest

DROP TABLE #StackTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CharIndex` and `Substring`

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (Value varchar(200))

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('Alexa, thank you for visiting Chicago! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Katana, thank you for visiting Dallas! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Siri, thank you for visiting New York City! We hope you come back soon!'),
('Bixby, thank you for visiting Seattle! We hope you come back soon!')

SELECT 'First Name' + SUBSTRING(sd.[Value], CHARINDEX(',', sd.[Value], 1), len(sd.[Value]) - CHARINDEX(',', sd.[Value], 1) + 1)
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Link demo: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/KSBI76692)